# How to download and Install VS 2012 in Windows 10

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2012

I would like to use VS 2012 and SQL 2012 in my personal laptop(It has windows 10).
Could you share the website where can I get free version(Not a trial version).
If possible please provide installation guide to them like which one should I install first VS or SQL ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to use 2012? The latest version, 2015, supports every development scenario that 2012 does, except for Windows 8 (not 8.1) "Modern" app development.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple editions of "free" VS 2012.

Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30669).

Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop
(https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34673).

Download VS Express for Web if you want to create ASP.NET Web Application projects.

Download VS Express for Windows Desktop if you want to create Windows Desktop projects.

Download Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Express here:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062.

If you would like to develop only web applications, you may download Microsoft Web Platform Installer 5.0 (https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx)
and use it to download and install "Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web (Latest)" and "Microsoft SQL Express LocalDB Edition 11.0".

The order of installation is not important.

Comment: `Serg, Thank you for your link. But I can't find this edition: "Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web". We're sorry, this download is no longer available.-shows. May be you have another links)))) I appreciate man))